# NoClassDefFoundError for LoginContext when starting Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I installed Android Studio a short while ago but I couldn't create an AVM because I didn't have intel VT enabled in my bios. So I went and enabled it but now when I try to run android studio I get this error:

```
Internal error. Please report to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gct/login/LoginContext
at com.google.gct.login.GoogleLogin.getClientInfo(GoogleLogin.java:519)
at com.google.gct.login.GoogleLogin.<init>(GoogleLogin.java:67)
at com.google.gct.login.GoogleLogin.getInstance(GoogleLogin.java:81)
at com.google.gct.login.ui.GoogleLoginActionButton.<init>(GoogleLoginActionButton.java:40)
at com.google.gct.login.ui.GoogleLoginAction.createCustomComponent(GoogleLoginAction.java:42)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.getCustomComponent(ActionToolbarImpl.java:326)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.fillToolBar(ActionToolbarImpl.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.access$1000(ActionToolbarImpl.java:64)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl$2.run(ActionToolbarImpl.java:943)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushRequest(FocusManagerImpl.java:651)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushNow(FocusManagerImpl.java:632)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushIdleRequests(FocusManagerImpl.java:602)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.access$200(FocusManagerImpl.java:60)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl$7.run(FocusManagerImpl.java:498)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2057)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:476)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.updateActions(ActionToolbarImpl.java:973)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.setMiniMode(ActionToolbarImpl.java:1336)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.<init>(ActionToolbarImpl.java:190)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.<init>(ActionToolbarImpl.java:151)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.createActionToolbar(ActionManagerImpl.java:213)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.createActionToolbar(ActionManagerImpl.java:208)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane.createToolbar(IdeRootPane.java:214)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane.updateToolbar(IdeRootPane.java:194)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane.<init>(IdeRootPane.java:99)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl.createRootPane(IdeFrameImpl.java:177)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl.<init>(IdeFrameImpl.java:96)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.WindowManagerImpl.showFrame(WindowManagerImpl.java:517)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:251)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:153)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:46)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gct.login.LoginContext      PluginClassLoader[com.google.gct.login, 1.0]
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:68)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 48 more
```

what should I do?